# How to write a query based on the Date item, in interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a date field and a interactive grid. I am trying to generate the Interactive grid based on the value inputted in the date field.

I am trying to write the query as below :

```
select pap.effective_start_date , pap.effective_end_date
from per_all_people_f pap
where :SELECT_DATE between pap.effective_start_date and 
pap.effective_end_date
```

Here, SELECT_DATE is the name of the Date field (datatype Date picker). I am writing a dynamic action on Change of Date field, and refreshing the interactive grid region. 
But when I change the value in Date field, it doesn't return any rows.

I have done a similar change where my interactive grid was based on a dropdown. There I had to set the "page action on selection" to Submit, and it worked. But here, since it is a Date field, the "Page Action on selection" property doesn't appear on the page .

Can somebody please suggest, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert your bind variables, which are treated as strings, to dates.

to_date(:SELECT_DATE)

The format mask will come from the application properties, or you can be explicit with that, too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion . I will try that. Meanwhile I switched to the Interactive report instead of Interactive grid and there it worked fine when i gave SELECT_DATE as 'page items to submit'.